# What function keys can I reliably detect (cross-browser) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

F1 obviously launches help, so that's no good.
F5 is refresh, also no good.
F6 focuses the address bar, no good.
F11 full-screen.
F12 dev-tools.

etc.

Can I rely on ANY f-keys in javascript?  Or do they all have special functions in one browser or another?

Comment: FWIW you may not need to immediately rule them out just because they have a native behaviour. Command+F usually triggers my browser's built-in search, but in Google Docs it activates their own search feature instead.

Comment: Fair point, thanks Jeremy.  I'd still be interested to know if there's any that are unused across the mainstream browsers though, even if I then put an override in (if possible) as a failsafe.

Comment: You should test it on your own anyway, even if someone gives you a list, so... just test it. But yes, I've trapped F* keys before